# get the new added characters to an input by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I know this seems a quite easy target.  I have an `input[type=text]`, and I want to detect the new added character(s) in it.  The normal way is:

```
$selector.keypress(function(e) {
    //do sth here
    var newchar = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
});
```

But the above method not working properly for some **browsers** on android devices.  Typing the android virtual keyboard will not fire the `keypress`.

Then I found the following method is better:

```
$selector.on('input', function(e){
    //do sth here
});
```

It works fine for android devices, and also, it can detect `cut/paste`.

Now the question is, is there a way to know the new added character(s) to the `input`?  Do I need to do the complicated string comparison during inputing each time, i.e. compare the previous string and the new string in the input box?  I said it's complicated because you may not always type in char(s) at the end, you may insert some char(s) in the middle of the previous string.  Think about this, the previous string in the input box is **"abc"**, the new string after pasting is **"abcxabc"**, how can we know the new pasted string is **"abcx"**, or **"xabc"**?

The method from keypress is quite simple:

```
String.fromCharCode(e.which);
```

So, is there similar way to do this by the `on('input')` method?

---

After reading Yeldar Kurmangaliyev's answer, I dived into this issue for a while, and find this is really more complicated than my previous expectation.  The key point here is that there's a way to get the cursor position by calling: `selectionEnd`.

As Yeldar Kurmangaliyev mentioned, his answer can't cover the situation:

> it is not working is when you select text and paste another text with
>   replacing the original one.

Based on his answer, I modified the `getInputedString` function as following:

```
    function getInputedString(prev, curr, selEnd) {
        if (selEnd === 0) {
          return "";
        }
        //note: substr(start,length) and substring(start,end) are different
        var preLen = prev.length;
        var curLen = curr.length;
        var index = (preLen > selEnd) ? selEnd : preLen;
        var subStrPrev;
        var subStrCurr;
        for(i=index; i > 0; i--){
            subStrPrev = prev.substr(0, i);
            subStrCurr = curr.substr(0, i);
            if (subStrCurr === subStrPrev) {
                var subInterval = selEnd - i;
                var interval = curLen - preLen;
                if (interval>subInterval) {
                    return curr.substring(i, selEnd+(interval-subInterval));
                }
                else{
                    return curr.substring(i, selEnd);
                }

            }
        }

        return curr.substring(0, selEnd);
    }
```

The code is quite self explanation.  The core idea is, no matter what character(s) were added(type or paste), the new content MUST be ended at the cursor position.

There's also one issue for my code, e.g. when the prev is `abcabc|`, you select them all, and paste `abc`, the return value from my code will be `""`.  Actually, I think it's reasonable, because for my scenario, I think this is just the same with delete the `abc` from previous `abcabc|`.

Also, I changed the `on('input')` event to `on('keyup')`, the reason is, for some android browsers, the `this.selectionEnd` will not work in a same way, e.g., the previous text is `abc|`, now I paste `de` and the current string will be `abcde|`, but depending on different browsers, the `this.selectionEnd` inside `on('input')` may be **3**, or **5**.  i.e. some browsers will report the cursor position before adding the input, some will report the cursor position after adding the input.

Eventually, I found `on('keyup')` worked in the same way for all the browsers I tested.

The whole demo is as following:

[DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/ascfLfo6/4/)

Working on the cross-browser compatibility is always difficult, especially when you need to consider the touch screen ones.  Hope this can help someone, and have fun.

Comment: Why do you need this? How are you going to use this? :) Note that a user can simply paste text into your input, and it will trigger `input` event as well.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Hi, I want to know the inputed char(s) and show them dynamically in a way like toast in android/ios app.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, that's what I want as well, also detect the pasted string.

Comment: Any way you have to keep track of the previous state and compare it with new value

Comment: sorry but i dont understand if you want to handle chars on android app or web pages because if you mean web pages so its not a android problem but andorid browser

Comment: @daremachine thanks a lot, I edited my question to make it clear.  Yes, it's not android problem, it's the browser on some touch screen devices will not listen the keypress event.  I mean web pages, not app.

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna Hi, that's one solution, but will not always work well, e.g. the old string is "abc", the new value is "abcxabc", how can we know the new pasted string is "abcx", or "xabc"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important notes:

- when a user types in a character, the cursor stands after it
- when a user pastes the text, the cursor is also located after the pasted text

Assuming this, we can try to suggest the inputed \ pasted string.

For example, when we have a string `abc` and it becomes `abcx|abc` (`|` is a cursor) - we know that actually he pasted "abcx", but not "xabc".

How do this algorithmically? Lets assume that we have the previous input `abc` and the current input: `abcx|abc` (cursor is after `x`).

The new one is of length 7, while the previous one is of length 4. It means that a user inputed 4 characters. Just return these four characters :)

The only case when it is not working is when you select text and paste another text with replacing the original one. I am sure you will come up with a solution for it yoruself :)
Here is the working snippet:

```js
function getInputedString(prev, curr, selEnd) {
  if (prev.length > curr.length) {
    console.log("User has removed \ cut character(s)");
    return "";
  }

  var lengthOfPasted = curr.length - prev.length;
  if (curr.substr(0, selEnd - lengthOfPasted) + curr.substr(selEnd) === prev)
  {  
      return curr.substr(selEnd - lengthOfPasted, lengthOfPasted);
  } else {
      console.log("The user has replaced a selection :(");
      return "n\\a";
  }
}

var prevText = "";

$("input").on('input', function() {
  var lastInput = getInputedString(prevText, this.value, this.selectionEnd);
  prevText = this.value;

  $("#result").text("Last input: " + lastInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div id="result">Start inputing...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Yeldar.  I think the key point here is the **selectionEnd**.  I dived into this for a while(as you know, there always be some browser compatibility issue), and I put my result into my question.  I choose you as the correct answer, coz I'm inspired by your idea. ;)